# Can't set object from openr page on IE10 : Error Function expected

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have sample code to prove my work

try to change code to lastest ie version but stiuck on ie10

I have object create on index.html 
and pass to parent frame1.html

frame1.html pass to frame2.html this page still set/get data

frame2.html open pageX.html

The problem happen when try to set value on pageX but can get value
when call function to set value page display error Function Expected

This code still work on ie9

I don't know about object behavior change between ie9 to ie10

This is my sample
it has 4 html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title> New Document </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var zo_gbl_data = new Object ( );
  </script>
</head>


  <frameset>
    <frame src='frame1.html'>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

frame1.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
     <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          var zo_gbl_data = parent . zo_gbl_data;

          function initObj() {
            zo_gbl_data . data_lv1 = new Object();
            zo_gbl_data . data_lv1 . data = 0;
          }

          function getObjectLv1() {
            alert(zo_gbl_data . data_lv1 . data);
          }

          function setObjectLv1() {
            zo_gbl_data . data_lv1 . data += 1;
          }

        initObj();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <input type='button' value='Set Object lv1' onclick='setObjectLv1()'><br>

            <input type='button' value='Get Object lv1' onclick='getObjectLv1()'><br>

            <input type='button' value='open menu' onclick='window.open("frame2.html", "_self")'>

            <input type='button' value='open Page' onclick='window.open("pageX.html", "", "", true)'>
    </body>
    </html>
```

frame2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
     <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var zo_gbl_data = getGbData();

      function getGbData() {
        return  ( parent . zo_gbl_data );
      }

      function getData() {
        var lo_data;
        lo_data = zo_gbl_data;
        alert(lo_data . data_lv1 . data);

      }

      function setObjectLv1() {
      var lo_data;
        lo_data = zo_gbl_data ;
        lo_data . data_lv1 . data += 1;
      }

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type='button' value='Get Opener' onclick='getData()'><br>
    <input type='button' value='set Data' onclick='setObjectLv1()'><br><br>
    <input type='button' value='open Page' onclick='window.open("pageX.html", "", "", true)'>
    </body>
    </html>
```

pageX.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
     <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var zo_gbl_data = getGbData();

      function getGbData() {
        return  ( opener . zo_gbl_data );
      }

      function getData() {
        var lo_data;
        lo_data = zo_gbl_data  ;
        alert(lo_data . data_lv1 . data);

      }

      function setObjectLv1() {
      var lo_data;
        lo_data = zo_gbl_data ;
        lo_data . data_lv1 .data += 1;
      }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type='button' value='Get Opener' onclick='getData()'><br>
    <input type='button' value='set Opener' onclick='setObjectLv1()'><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for my English
I mean pageX was open by frame2